# Target child element with hover in Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a parent div with a child image element inside of it.
When I hover over the parent div I want my child element's src to change to a different source. But I'm struggling to find a way to do this with tailwind.

```
    <button className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-40 h-40 mx-12 transition ease-in-out rounded-full shrink-0 text-primary hover:text-white hover:bg-light">
        <div className="relative flex items-center justify-center w-20 h-20 mb-2">
            <Image src={icon} alt={`${title} icon`} />
        </div>
        <span className="text-xl text-center">{title}</span>
    </button>
```

[image]

Image should turn white (different source) on hover. How to do this with Tailwind?

Comment: I think that this is either job for javascript or dont use Image but background of div

Comment: I'm willing to use background of div, but i dont know how to do that either in tailwind @Wraithy

Comment: you can use `<div className="bg-[url('/img/hero-pattern.svg')]">`

Comment: @Wraithy i tried this but it's in a loop so the url is dynamic and string interpolation somehow doesnt work with tailwind.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one solution that lets you set up two images in advance and switch between them using `group-hover`.

```html
<button class="relative flex flex-col items-center justify-center group w-20 h-20 m-12 rounded-full text-primary">
  <img class="absolute group-hover:invisible w-20 h-20 rounded-full" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/100/100"/>
  <img class="absolute invisible group-hover:visible w-20 h-20 rounded-full" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/100/100"/>
  <span class="absolute top-10 text-xl text-center text-green-500 group-hover:text-white">title</span>
</button>
```

You can test it in the Tailwind sandbox here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/CCvbvcYNVv